# Кто-нибудь может помочь разобраться с асинхронным взаимодействием между микросервисами (masstransit)?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

Приведу сферический пример из головы, чтобы было нагляднее:

Допустим у нас есть два микросервиса со своими базами данных. Первый служит для заполнения данных, второй для формирования из этих данных PDF для печати.

В первом микросервисе происходит создание карточки студента, заполнение её персональными данными и прикрепление фотографии. Иными словами есть WEB API и три метода, которые вызываются в сл. порядке:

1. CreateStudentCard()
2. PutPersonalData()
3. PutPhoto()

В первом методе CreateStudentCard() происходит создание карточки студента, генерация её ID и сохранение в базу с этим ID, в качестве первичного ключа.
В остальных двух методах мы, используя полученный ID карточки студента в качестве внешнего ключа, сохраняем в другие соотв. таблицы персональные данные и фото.

В каждом из этих трех методов, после сохранения в базу, происходит отправка события на шину RabbitMQ с использованием библиотеки MassTransit. В первом методе, после сохранения карточки в базу, происходит отправка сообщения StudentCardCreated, которое содержит ID карточки и дату создания. Во втором методе, соответственно, отправка события PersonalDataUpdated с данными студента, в третьем PhotoUpdated с фотографией.

Во втором микросервисе мы подписаны на все эти три события. Иными словами - есть три асинхронных Consumer'а, которые получат асинхронно три эти сообщения для того, что бы уже в своей базе создать карточку студента, с тем же ID, что и в микросервисе источнике, и прикрепить к ней персональные данные и фото.

И вот тут начинается суть вопроса:

Каждый асинхронный consumer-потребитель в своей реализации имеет методы обращения к контексту данных, которые так же асинхронны (в частности LINQ-методы EntityFramework).
И вот первый consumer, который прослушивает событие StudentCardCreated получает сообщение. Внутри него мы, прежде чем сразу взять и сохранить пришедшую карточку, вызываем какой-то асинхронный метод, для проверки чего-либо в базе, используя await (допустим AnyAsync). Как только в этом consumer'e вызывается await, управление вернется вызывающему потоку, который тут же подхватит следующее событие из очереди и вызывает consumer для второго сообщения PersonalDataUpdated.
В таком случае есть риск, что consumer для PersonalDataUpdated дойдет до сохранения в базу данных раньше, чем создастся сама карточка студента в consumer'e для StudentCardCreated, что, разумеется приведет к ошибке, так как нам нужен ID карточки в качестве внешнего ключа, ведь мы не можем прикрепить данные и фото к карточке, которой не существует в базе.

Думаю, что я не до конца понимаю логику работы с брокером либо то, как работает асинхронность в данном случае. Может быть, кто-то сможет подсказать, как правильно такие ситуации разрешаются и может быть такой подход вообще в корне неверный?

Набросал в пейнте схему того, что я имею в виду. Стрелочками и цифрами обозначен тот порядок действий, как я его вижу

[image: схема]

Answer (score 4):

Пойдем по пунктам:

1. Если у вас три метода всегда вызываеются один за другим, может это должен быть один метод?
2. По идее, в идеале, сообщения, которые через шину проходят, должны быть идемпотентны (то есть то же сообщение каждый раз дает одинаковый результат). И также порядок сообщений не должен быть проблемой. Если у вас порядок, в котором приходят сообщения, важен для вашей логики, вы, возможно, что то делаете не так в своей архитектуре.
3. Непонятен смысл дублирования информации. Зачем хранить одно и то же в каждом сервисе. Если вам надо получить доступ к карточке студента - обращайтесь к микросервису с карточками студентов.
4. Ваши размышления, что будет обработано первым, а что вторым. Очереди бывают разные. Бывает, например, очередь с негарантированным порядком сообщений. Более того, если у вас микросервис, то у вас может быть несколько экземпляров сервиса, которые могут независимо обрабатывать ваши сообщения.

Подытожу.

1. Если хотите правильнор делать - пересмотрите вашу архитектуру.
2. Если хотите сделать костыль поверх костыля, то смотрите в сторону distributed lock, то есть lock на уровне базы данных, например.